# ¿Cómo prevenir recarga del Activity o Fragment al rotar etc. en Android?

Tags: java, android

Me encuentro que cuando le das la vuelta al dispositivo o bien si se oculta el teclado el `Activity` es restablecido de nuevo, pasando por `onCreate()` de nuevo.

Una posible solución seria usar `savedInstanceState` guardando una variable de estado, pero no ser si es la mejor solución.

¿Se puede prevenir de alguna forma, la recarga de nuevo del `Activity en rotar, o otros eventos posibles que lo hagan restablecer de nuevo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu definición de actividad dentro de `AndroidManifest.xml` agrega la propiedad:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

por ejemplo:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".myActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"            
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Con esto no recarga la actividad al realizar una rotación, no ejecuta nuevamente  el método `onCreate()`

Comment: Gracias, veo que el mundo de Android se puede solventar casi todo fácilmente

Comment: Bueno, dependiendo de los requerimientos de la aplicación, en algunas ocasiones se requiere que la actividad sea destruida para mostrar otro tipo de distribución ;).

Comment: Te funciono? A mi no.
Ya probe con todas las posibles funciones aparte de KeyboardHidden y screensize y nada.