# ¿Como puedo mantener información cuando giro la pantalla del móvil?

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación muy simple que me cuenta el numero de veces que pulso, pero cada vez que giro la pantalla pierde el numero de veces que he pulsado y vuelve a 0. ¿Como puedo evitar que eso suceda?

Comment: Hola Adrián Sanz. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mostrar tu codigo para poder contextualizarnos... si no esta pregunta es muy amplia. ¿Has usado el **modo debug** para ir instruccion a instruccion y ver donde puede estar cambiando? . Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Utiliza los SharedPreferences que no es más que los datos con los que trabaja tu app almacenadas bajo el directorio de tu aplicación, de manera que puedas acceder a el cuando sucede eso que expones.

Comment: Puedes agregar algo parecido a esto `android:configChanges="orientation"` en el `AndroidManifest.xml`, donde defines tu Activity...: **`<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation">`**. Por supuesto, cambia `MyActivity` por el nombre de tu Actividad. Consulta la documentación, hay otras formas de hacerlo si lo prefieres: [Manejo de cambios en tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: En el sitio puedes encontrar información acerca de esto por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4342/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-recarga-del-activity-o-fragment-al-rotar-etc-en-android/4348#4348 o realiza una búsqueda https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%3AconfigChanges Te recomiendo realices mejores preguntas para evitar sean cerradas.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes emplear varios métodos para resolver tu problema. El más simple es el uso de las Preferencias Compartidas (SharedPreference), con lo cual puedes almacenar datos y posteriormente leerlos a tu gusto. El problema con tu app es que al voltearla, cambia el ciclo de vida de tu proyecto, por tanto se vuelve a llamar la función onCreate de tu Activity, lo que debes hacer es en los distintos estados salvar tu dato y al crear la actividad leerlos en caso de que existan.

```
//Nombre que le voy asignar a mi SharedPreference
public static final String SHARED_PREF = "com.example.app";
//Clave con la que almacenaré el contador
public static final String COUNTER_KEY = "counter";
//Contador usado para registrar las pulsaciones (Este es el valor que querias almacenar)
int counter = 0;
SharedPreference sharedP;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 //Esto es por defecto
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //Creo la Preferencia compartida
  sharedP = getSharedPreference(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  //Leo los datos del contador y si no existe le asigno 0
  counter = sharedP.getInt(COUNTER_KEY, 0);
}

//Salvo los datos al SharedPreference para que permanezcan para su uso posteriormente
private void SaveData(){
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedP.edit();
  editor.putInt(COUNTER_KEY, counter);
  editor.commit();
 }

//Cuando se va a destruir la Actividad
public void onDestroy(){
  SaveData();
  super.onDestroy();
}

//Cuando se detiene la actividad
public void onStop(){
  SaveData();
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera en la configuración de tu actividad en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

En dicho archivo encontrarás ya la configuración de tus actividades. Supongamos que quieres evitar que al girar la pantalla de la actividad llamada `TuActivity` se pierda el contenido, buscas su configuración y agregas esta línea: **`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`**.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".TuActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
  </activity>
```

De esa forma, no se perderá el contenido al girar la pantalla.

Para más detalles consulta:  [Manejo de cambios en tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) de la documentación de Android.

*Nota:* En algunas versiones de la API de Android funcionaría sin usar el último parámetro:

**`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`**