# FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

Tags: android, android-studio, timer

estoy mostrando en un fragment, una secuencia de tres imagenes a través de un ViewPager, he agregado al fragment un temporizador TimerTask para las imagenes, ocasionalmente se genera un error que cierra la aplicación y se refiere a la línea:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

Antes había hecho este ejercicio pero en una Activity y esta linea estaba así:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

A continuación muestro el código del fragment y dos pantallas de Logcat, adradezco su ayuda.

Fragment_Home

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

//ViewPager
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAadapter adapter;

public Fragment_Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAadapter(getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 3000, 4000);

    return v;
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==2){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
    return getFragmentManager();
}
}
```

Imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que no encuentra la `Activity` para llamar `runOnUiThread()`, esto puede suceder por ejemplo cuando giras tu dispositivo, la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment` se destruye pero tienes programada la ejecución de una tarea, si la `Activity` se destruye momentáneamente puede suceder que la instancia de `Activity` tenga valor null y no puedas llamar:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread()
```

En este caso te recomiendo validar si `getActivity()` existe:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

       if(getActivity() != null) {  

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              ...
              ...
            }
        });

       }

    }
}
```

Otra opción es que definas dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` la siguiente propiedad a la `Activity` que carga el `Fragment`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

[¿Cómo prevenir recarga del Activity o Fragment al rotar etc. en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4342/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-recarga-del-activity-o-fragment-al-rotar-etc-en-android)

Comment: Muchas gracias lo he agregado a mi código, éxito.

Comment: La opción del AndroidManifest.xml se me hace más simple pero apliqué la del condicional.

Comment: Excelente @Alfredo, saludos!