# Se me cierra la app al rotar la pantalla android studio

Tags: android

Todo funciona bien, todo se adapta bien, sin embargo una noche probando los últimos cambios que fueron hacer que suene un sonido al no digitar todos los campos, la aplicación comenzó a cerrarse al momento de rotar la pantalla.

No tengo idea por qué sucede eso, así que descomprimí una respaldo anterior lo ejecuté y también se me cierra la aplicación al rotar la pantalla.

¿Alguien conoce una solución o el por qué sucede eso?

```
2021-09-14 11:54:24.539 23672-23672/com.example.sgse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sgse, PID: 23672
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sgse/com.example.sgse.PrincipalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.sgse:layout/activity_principal: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.sgse:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.sgse:layout/activity_principal: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.sgse:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.sgse:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sgse.ui.ingresarCuenta.depositos.Fragment_Ingresar_Depositos.onCreateView(Fragment_Ingresar_Depositos.java:21)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
```

Comment: Que s muestra en el LogCat, agrega el código que realizas, edita tu pregunta agregando más información , revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Al parecer tenía que configurar el manifest y poner en la activity           android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
Aunque no sé por qué ahora me pide eso, si antes funcionaba bien, pero bueno, cada día se aprende algo nuevo

Comment: definiendo android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  no se va a destruir la Activity, sería buena idea agregaras que error marca sin android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  tal vez es otra cosa que pudiera corregirse.

Comment: Que sucede si inicias la app en la orientación que marca error? @Apreniendo

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12
> in com.example.sgse:layout/activity_principal: Binary XML file line
> #10 in com.example.sgse:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.sgse:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)'
> on a null object reference

cuando giras el dispositivo no encuentra la referencia a el `ActionBar`, probablemente se esta haciendo uso de otro layout que se carga al girar en el cual  no se tiene este elemento.

Si funciona inicialmente podrías evitar la reconstrucción de la Activity mediante:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".PrincipalActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Revisa:

[¿Cómo prevenir recarga del Activity o Fragment al rotar etc. en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4342/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-recarga-del-activity-o-fragment-al-rotar-etc-en-android)